# How to use fetched data for argument in a method

Tags: javascript, methods, fetch

I'm trying to make an application that gets all the planets from SWAPI and then displays them as boxes on the page. I have **_load()** method, which fetches the data, and **_render()** method, which is supposed to render the boxes. The **_render()** has ***name, terrain, population*** parameters.

Here is part of my code:

```
const box = document.createElement("div");
    box.classList.add("box");
    box.innerHTML = this._render({
      name: '',
      terrain: "placeholder",
      population: 0,
    });

    document.body.querySelector(".main").appendChild(box);

    this.emit(Application.events.READY);
  }
```

**_load()** where I fetch the data

```js
async function getPlanets() {
      const urls = Array.from({ length: 7 },
        (v, i) => `https://swapi.boom.dev/api/planets?page=${i + 1}`);

      const promises = urls.map(url => fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data.results));

      const planetData = (await Promise.all(promises)).flat();
      console.log(`Results for ${planetData.length} planets downloaded...`);
      console.log('Results:', planetData);
    }
    getPlanets()
```

And here is the **_render()**

```
_render({ name, terrain, population }) {
    return `
<article class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <figure class="image is-64x64">
      <img src="${image}" alt="planet">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="media-content">
    <div class="content">
    <h4>${name}</h4>
      <p>
        <span class="tag">${terrain}</span> <span class="tag">${population}</span>
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
    `;
  }
```

What I need to do is get the **value** for these **parameters** from the **fetched data**.

**Pastebin** - https://pastebin.com/hbxfHC1U

Comment: Do you mean, how do you pass the values from `planetData` to the `_render` method? Could you modify your code so it can run in a stack snippet (look for `<>` icon in your question editor)?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier that's exactly what i want to do, yes

Comment: Cool. It is not yet clear how the `_render`, `_load` and your first snippet are connected. Could you provide the class they exist in. That way I will know how you call `_load` and other methods, and how I should call them aswell.

Comment: here's a pastebin - https://pastebin.com/hbxfHC1U

Comment: You've said what you want to do.  So go for it!  What is your question?  Where are you actually stuck?  Are you just stuck on the [schema](https://swapi.dev/documentation#schema) of the data coming back from the swapi?

Comment: @wyck I don’t know how to pass the values to _render(), that’s why I need help

Comment: Did you try: `_render(planetData[0])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your pastebin snippet I've made some adjustments.

First modify your `_load` function so that it returns the result the result from the SWAPI request. I've removed the function that you define within it, because it seemed unnesseccary and you're already inside of an `async` context.

Use the returned value of `_load` in your `constructor` and pass it to `_create`. (Your comments stated that this was your intention, anyway). Within `_create` loop over the data, create your box and call the `_render` method by passing the properties that you need from each item.

```js
class Application {
  constructor() {
    this._startLoading()
    this._load()
      .then(data => this._create(data))
      .then(() => this._stopLoading())
  }

  async _load() {
    const urls = Array.from({
        length: 7
      },
      (v, i) => `https://swapi.boom.dev/api/planets?page=${i + 1}`);

    const promises = urls.map(url => fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => data.results));

    const planetData = await Promise.all(promises)
    return planetData.flat();
  }
  
    //here should be moved the rendering of the boxes, I suppose by establishing a connection with _render()
  _create(data) {
    data.forEach(({ name, terrain, population }) => {
      const box = document.createElement("div");
      box.classList.add("box");
      
      box.innerHTML = this._render({
        name,
        terrain,
        population,
      });
      
      document.body.querySelector(".main").appendChild(box);
    })
  }

  _render({ name, terrain, population, image = '' }) {
    return `
<article class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <figure class="image is-64x64">
      <img src="${image}" alt="planet">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="media-content">
    <div class="content">
    <h4>${name}</h4>
      <p>
        <span class="tag">${terrain}</span> <span class="tag">${population}</span>
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
    `;
  }

  // we can leave these two alone for now
  _startLoading() {
    console.log('loading');
  }

  _stopLoading() {
    console.log('finished');
  }

}

new Application();
```

```html
<main class="main"></main>
```